# Storing array values in two database tables

Tags: php, arrays, database

I have an array, I just print it as print_r($data) which looks like-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title
            [1] => Featured Image
            [2] => Catagories
            [3] => Tags
            [4] => Content
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => title 1
            [1] => img1.jpg
            [2] => cat 1
            [3] => tag 1
            [4] => post 1 content
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => title 2
            [1] => img2.jpg
            [2] => cat2
            [3] => tag 2
            [4] => post 2 content
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => title 3
            [1] => img3.jpg
            [2] => cat3
            [3] => tag3
            [4] => post 3 content
        )
}
```

I have two tables-
   1) sa_posts
   2) sa_terms
In sa_posts table I want to store title, feature image, content and in sa_terms table I have to store categories and tags.
How is this possible using foreach or for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get array values by keys, and write insert query for below values

```
<?php 
 foreach($data as $d)
 {
    //sa_posts values title=$d[0],  feature image=$d[1], content = $d['4']
    //sa_terms values categories =$d[2], tags=$d[3]
 }
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

`Foreach` is your friend with arrays.

```
foreach($array as $element) {
  //sql insert to sa_posts for $element[0], $element[1], $element[2]
  //sql insert to sa_terms for $element[3], $element[4]
}
```

Personally, I've not seen an array whose first element describes the contents of the rest, though. If this isn't common practice, I'd consider using an associative array instead otherwise you'll be forever skipping the first element of your array and if you forget, you're going to end up with some weird data.